# VSCode ignoring falsy unions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

For some strange reason VSCode is showing these falsey unions as just `number` when they should represent `number` or `null` as in the first `example` or `number` or `undefined` in the second.

```
type example = number | null // shows as just 'number'
```

```
type example = number | undefined // shows as just 'number'
```

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: report this in vscode issues in github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)

Comment: Do you have strict null checking enabled?